# What is the difference between ‘I'm never having a beard when I grew up’’ and 'I will never have a beard when I grew up'? Request

Tags: sentence-meaning, tense, present-tense, future-tense

What is the difference between ‘I'm never having a beard when I grew up’’ and 'I will never have a beard when I grew up'?

Are the two sentences the same in meaning or they are different?

Comment: They're the same, although we might say "grow a beard" rather than "have a beard".

Answer (score 5):

The two are very similar and could easily be interpreted to mean the same thing, but there are subtle differences in what the speaker might have meant:

With ***I'm never having*** the speaker might be resolving to never have a beard, because he really doesn't want one. (This is progressive tone; we hear the future lack of a beard as something the speaker will maintain by force of will.)

With ***I'll never have*** the speaker might have concluded that he (she?) is permanently unable to grow a beard, either physically (perhaps genetically, or perhaps a skin disease), or perhaps a rich aunt's will prohibits bearded relatives from inheriting. (This implies a pefective aspect; we hear the future lack of a beard as something out of the speaker's control).

It's a little farfetched in the specific case of beards: you really have to strain to think of a plausible situation for the "I'll never have" version.

But the difference is much easier to see between **"I'm never having a Mercedes"** (from an Audi lover) and **"I'll never have a Mercedes"** (sigh, I'll never be able to afford one).

Comment: Interesting. I didn't pick up on that "force of will" vs. "ability" difference, but you're right.  You can imagine some fuzzy-cheeked teenage boy whining "I'll never have a beard!"  :)

Answer (score 2):

These are the two different forms the Simple Future tense in English:

1. **Be going to** (written as "I'm never having", implied as "I am never going to" in your question), and
2. **Will** (written as "I will never" in your question)

The two can generally be used interchangeably, although they typically express subtly different meaning. For example, form #1 will be used more often to indicate something being done *to* the subject, while form #2 almost always indicates something the subject *will him or herself do*.

In many cases the "simple will" form (#2 above) is considered more direct and generally clearer language. The statement imparts more confidence and may therefore be the preferred choice in many cases.

One other note: something that makes your first phrase sound less articulate than the second is that you've used "having" instead of "going to have" (or even better..."going to *grow*"). For example, it would sound better to say "I am never going to grow a beard when I grow up."

In this case, given the way you're written both sentences, their meaning would be the same.

[Reference](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplefuture.html)